# Looping data through an excel sheet using python

Tags: python, excel, selenium, loops

I have the following code that goes through my excel sheet lists all my data

```
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook('book2.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_name('combo2')

for i in range(sheet.nrows):
    print (sheet.row_values(i))
```

Code returns
['2', '3', '4', 'r', 'h', 'w', 'w']
['5', '6', '7', 'r', 'h', 'w', 'e']
which works, but I want to be able to take the "2" place it somewhere on a forum using selenium then take the 3 and put it somewhere else in the forum and do the same thing until I reach the "w" on in the first list. but then I need it to loop throughout the 2nd list doing the same thing, obviously, once the code is fully implemented it would go through hundreds of these lists, I'm still a beginner as you can see but I can manage my way through selenium, where I'm having trouble is the part where I need to single the digits or letters inside the list then have them saved as a string then looping to the next list. I've considered using dictionaries but that approach seemed to make a viable solution more complex

Thanks

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Maybe read up on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask -- asking a specific question about a reproducible problem would help you get useful, good answers.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by, "single the digits or letters inside the list"?

Answer (score 0):

is it something that you wanted ?

```
df = pd.read_excel('/folder/filename.xlsx', sheet_name='sheets')
for x in df.index:
   print(df['col_name'][x])
```